# Rails: How to name and create unique divs within a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, loops

I have a view with a div that is looped many times. Each of the created divs need to have a unique ID so I can access them specifically (at the moment, all my divs have the same ID specified in html so whenever I try to access a specific div it just finds the first one).

This is the version that I currently have (multiple 'rowBox'es are not discernible).

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <div id="customer" class="rowBox">
  ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <div id="box<%=customer.id%>">
  ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has [some handy helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html) for exactly this.

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <%= div_for customer, :class => "rowBox" do %>
    ...
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will produce e.g.:

```
<div id="customer_1" class="customer rowBox">
  ...
</div>

<div id="customer_2" class="customer rowBox">
  ...
</div>

......
```

Comment: If they're new objects this won't work.  You can also use `each_with_index do |c, i|` which will give you a loop counter.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <div id=<%= "box#{customer.id}" -%>>
  ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Sorry for earlier omission. This should work.